# prioritise ES search results for some fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-6.4.3. I have created an index `flight-location_methods`

```
      settings index: {
          analysis: {
              "filter": {
                  "autocomplete_filter": {
                      "type": "edge_ngram",
                      "min_gram": 1,
                      "max_gram": 20
                  }
              },
              "analyzer": {
                  "autocomplete": {
                      "type": "custom",
                      "tokenizer": "standard",
                      "filter": ["lowercase",  "autocomplete_filter"]
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      mapping do
        indexes :airport_code, type: "text", analyzer: "autocomplete", search_analyzer: "standard"
        indexes :airport_name, type: "text", analyzer: "autocomplete", search_analyzer: "standard"
        indexes :city_name, type: "text", analyzer: "autocomplete", search_analyzer: "standard"
        indexes :country_name, type: "text", analyzer: "autocomplete", search_analyzer: "standard"
      end
```

The above snippet is from the ruby code which `represents the mapping` I have created for the index.

When I am executing this query:

```
GET /flight-location_methods/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "city_name": "new yo"
            }
          },
          "weight": 50
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "country_name": "new yo"
            }
          },
          "weight": 50
        }
      ],
      "max_boost": 200,
      "score_mode": "max",
      "boost_mode": "multiply",
      "min_score": 10
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting this result:

```
  {
    "_index": "flight-location_methods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "tcoj1G0Bdo5Q9AduxCKi",
    "_score": 50,
    "_source": {
      "airport_name": "Ouvea",
      "airport_code": "UVE",
      "city_name": "Ouvea",
      "country_name": "New Caledonia"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "flight-location_methods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "zMoj1G0Bdo5Q9AduxCKi",
    "_score": 50,
    "_source": {
      "airport_name": "Palmerston North",
      "airport_code": "PMR",
      "city_name": "Palmerston North",
      "country_name": "New Zealand"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "flight-location_methods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1Moj1G0Bdo5Q9AduxCKi",
    "_score": 50,
    "_source": {
      "airport_name": "Westport",
      "airport_code": "WSZ",
      "city_name": "Westport",
      "country_name": "New Zealand"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "flight-location_methods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1coj1G0Bdo5Q9AduxCKi",
    "_score": 50,
    "_source": {
      "airport_name": "Whangarei",
      "airport_code": "WRE",
      "city_name": "Whangarei",
      "country_name": "New Zealand"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "flight-location_methods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "Rsoj1G0Bdo5Q9AduxCOi",
    "_score": 50,
    "_source": {
      "airport_name": "Municipal",
      "airport_code": "RNH",
      "city_name": "New Richmond",
      "country_name": "United States"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "flight-location_methods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "fsoj1G0Bdo5Q9AduxCOi",
    "_score": 50,
    "_source": {
      "airport_name": "New London",
      "airport_code": "GON",
      "city_name": "New London",
      "country_name": "United States"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "flight-location_methods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "gMoj1G0Bdo5Q9AduxCOi",
    "_score": 50,
    "_source": {
      "airport_name": "New Ulm",
      "airport_code": "ULM",
      "city_name": "New Ulm",
      "country_name": "United States"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "flight-location_methods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "5coj1G0Bdo5Q9AduxCSi",
    "_score": 50,
    "_source": {
      "airport_name": "Cape Newenham",
      "airport_code": "EHM",
      "city_name": "Cape Newenham",
      "country_name": "United States"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "flight-location_methods",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "Ycoj1G0Bdo5Q9AduxCWi",
    "_score": 50,
    "_source": {
      "airport_name": "East 60th Street H/P",
      "airport_code": "JRE",
      "city_name": "New York",
      "country_name": "United States"
    }
  }
```

As you can see, `New York should be on top` but actually it's not.

Also, I `can not use AND operator` because I want any of the words in the search text to appear in any of the fields if the search text has multiple words. But, if all the search text is present in one field, the priority should be higher.

Comment: Could you please share some sample data set? Your question not trivial enough and require testing.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ArQiZjKz  , let me know if this is helpful to you.

Comment: All your results have a score of 50. Run it with query param: `?explain=true` and you will be able to figure out how the words are being tokenized and why they are receiving the scores. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first discuss the elasticsearch tokenizer and tokenization process:

> A tokenizer receives a stream of characters, breaks it up into individual tokens (usually individual words). *[ES docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/analysis-tokenizers.html)*

Now let's describe how to **autocomplete analyzer** work:

1. standard tokenizer is provided tokens as standard elasticsearch tokenizer (for simplification let's tell that this is words)
2. lowercase filter makes all characters lower.
3. then edge_ngram filter breaks each word to tokens.

From here start magic: I think that your definition for a token from 1 to 20 is too much. Might be exists words that include more than 10 characters but for our case, it's not relevant. Also, token that include only one character not usable for us. I change it:

```
   "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 5
        }
      }
```

Then in our index will be a lot of word parts with a length from 2 to 5 characters. Now when we know what we search we can create mapping and write queries:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 3,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 5
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "airport_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "autocomplete"
            }
          }
        },
        "airport_code": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "autocomplete"
            }
          }
        },
        "city_name": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "autocomplete"
            }
          }
        },
        "country_name": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "autocomplete"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I make fields with ngram field and regular field to keeping the ability to make aggregations. This is good to find cities by a number of airports for example.

Now we can run a simple query to get New York:

```
{
   "size": 20, 
   "query": {
     "query_string": {
       "default_field": "city_name.ngram",
       "query": "new yo",
       "default_operator": "AND"
     }
   }
}

Answer
{
  "took": 15,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 13.896059,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "BtBD2W0BCDulLSY6pKM8",
        "_score": 13.896059,
        "_source": {
          "airport_name": "Flushing",
          "airport_code": "FLU",
          "city_name": "New York",
          "country_name": "United States"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or create [boosting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-boosting-query.html) or [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html) query with boosting. This is also will be more efficient in the query on a big data list.

And your query should look as:

```
{
   "query": {
     "function_score": {
       "query": {
         "query_string": {
           "query": "new yo",
           "analyzer": "autocomplete"
         }
       },
       "functions": [
         {
           "filter": {"terms": {
             "city_name.ngram": [
               "new",
               "yo"
             ]
           }},
           "weight": 2
         },
         {
           "filter": {"terms": {
             "country_name.ngram": [
               "new",
               "yo"
             ]
           }},
           "weight": 2
         }
       ],
       "max_boost": 30,
       "min_score": 5, 
       "score_mode": "max",
       "boost_mode": "multiply"
     }
   }
}
```

In this query, New York will be first because we filter all not relevant documents by the query part. And multiple by 2 city_name.ngram field score and in this field, we have 2 tokens then this filed will receive a max score. Also, the bottom line of a query is min_score that filters, not relevant documents. You can read about the current elasticsearch relevance algorithm [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-1-how-shards-affect-relevance-scoring-in-elasticsearch).
By the way, I wouldn't like to put filters in functions with the same weight. You should decide about are more significant field. This makes your search more clear.